# Dynamic confidence intervals for Bernoulli trails

Tags: estimation, bernoulli-distribution, random-walk

Let $\dots, X_i, \dots\sim B(p)$ be iid. Bernoulli random variables with mean $p$,
then we know from Chernoff bounds that $\Pr[\left|1-\frac{1}{np}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right|>\epsilon]\le2\exp(-\epsilon^2 n p\,/\,3)$.
In other words, we have the confidence interval $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\in p\,(1\pm\epsilon)$ with probability $\ge1-\delta$ if $n\ge3p^{-1}\epsilon^{-2}\log1/\delta$.

My question is about the "Dynamic case", in which we have access to an infinite sequence of $X_i$ and want to estimate $p$ with as few trials as needed.
Is there a simple stopping rule we can use in this case?

For example:
Let $n_1$ be the number of variables seen so far with value 1, and let $n_0$ be the number of 0s seen.
Then we might estimate $p\approx \frac{\min\{n_1,n_0\}}{n_1+n_0}$, and the equirement on $n$ above becomes
$$ \min\{n_1,n_0\} \ge 3 \epsilon^{-2}\log1/\delta.$$
If we stop once this happens, we assume the estimate of $p$ is pretty good.

However, this is all heuristic. Can we actually prove that the above condition suffices? And if it doesn't, is there another condition we can use?

I realize this is probably a very well studied question in statistics, but I haven't been able to find anything on it.
I assume the above can be made more rigorous using some union bound argument, but that probably cost me at least a factor $\log n$ in the number of trials needed, and I would like something as sharp as possible.